# How to get multiple values from single textarea?

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, textarea, multiple-value

I want to enter and get multiple values from a single textarea. Like when we share something on facebook it allows us to enter multiple friends in a single textarea. And then share the post to all we have entered. How can i do this?
And I am using Zend

Comment: Split them on a new line when you get them from one field, simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tagsinput` plugin for adding multiple values through the same textbox. You can check it out through this [link](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/)